# Unity DI container performance with increased Type registrations

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

How Unity DI container perform with increased Type registrations. Lets take a scenario where we need to register 10000 different Types, what will be the performance impact in Type registrations and Resolving the Types (Transient).

Thanks
Pushkar

Answer (score 1):

Unity uses a dictionary internally, so you can expect the amount of time it takes to resolve on instance to stay constant over the number of registrations in the container. This holds for most containers. There are however other factors that may slow it down though, such as:

- The depth of the object graph of the objects being resolved.
- The number of threads that access the Unity container simultaneously.
- The addition of special features such as interception.